# UITableView scroll direction

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sdk

Is there anyway to know if a `UITableView` is scrolling towards the upper or the lower end of the table ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no single function/property to do that. I think the easiest way to get the direction is to save current content offset in delegate's `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` method and compare it to the current offset value in delegate's `scrollViewDidScroll:` method.

Comment: +1 / Remember, UITableView inherits from UIScrollView and so too are the delegates